# Run single test data entry in Intellij in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, spock

Lets consider simple test case with some test data in Spock

```
def "numbers to the power of two"(int a, int b, int c) {
  expect:
      Math.pow(a, b) == c

  where:
      a | b | c
      1 | 2 | 1
      2 | 2 | 4
      3 | 2 | 9
  }
```

Is it possible with vanilla Intellij or with some plugin to run just single test data entry? For example just `1 | 2 | 1` without needing to comment out all others?

Comment: No, intellij doesn't support that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible with vanilla Intellij or with some plugin to run just single test data entry?*

**No**